# Is it safe to hardcode /etc/ path for configurations in an application I'm contributing to?

Tags: etc, portability

The application I'm contributing to requires configuration files as a part of its operation. This is currently placed within the root directory of the application.
If I followed the FHS, the config should be stored in `/etc/Shinobi`. The operating systems supported by the app are

- Ubuntu 17.10.1 and 18.04
- CentOS 7
- MacOS 10.7(+)

Is it safe to assume that `/etc/` Directory will always exist in an operating system and read the default configuration from `/etc/Shinobi` throwing appropriate warnings if the directory is missing?

Comment: Some ideas (I don't know what is normally done). I would think that at the very least it should be `${dir_that_bin_is_in}/../etc/…` that will allow it to be placed in `/usr/local`. Another option is to specify it in `./configure`.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor but if you specify a relative path, you cannot move the software or use it on a system where it is installed elsewhere. It seems far safer to use `/etc`. What if the program is installed in `/bin` or `/sbin` or `/usr/bin` instead of `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: On macOS, '/etc' is a symlink to '/private/etc'.  '/usr/local/etc' is a potential choice, especially since '/usr/local/' is a standard and generally in the PATH.

Comment: @terdon If the application is to be used "where it is installed elsewhere", putting the configuration files in `/etc` means every system the application is to be used on has to be configured.  At least with a relative path, if the app is located in /path/to/app/bin` and the configuration is in `/path/to/app/bin/../etc`, sharing `/path/to/app` is sufficient to share the app on multiple systems in a way that doesn't need local configuration in `/etc` on all systems the app is to be used on.  This question makes me wonder what problem moving the configuration from its current location is solving.

Comment: @AndrewHenle yes, but since `/etc` is pretty standard, using that for configuration is probably the most portable solution. If you want to avoid that, just keep all the information in one directory which can be defined at install time. Then, the program will know to search in _that_ directory. But expecting your config dir to be exactly N directories above you is bound to fail.

Comment: @JRFerguson for those of us less familiar with macosx is storing something in /private/etc (/etc) considdered bad practice? Why are you suggesting against using it?

Comment: @Phillip Couling No, there's no bad practice in choosing '/private/etc'.

Answer (score 3):

You are changing the fundamental nature of the application by doing this, making it no longer self-contained within a single filesystem tree.
This might be not what your users want; nor how your application is used, distributed, and installed in practice.
If your application installs self-contained from a single archive into a single filesystem sub-tree as [a "portable application" install](https://gitlab.com/Shinobi-Systems/ShinobiPortable), you will break this.
If [your application doco recommends this as the best way to install it](https://shinobi.video/docs/start#content-the-easiest-way-portable), you break things for a lot of your users.

You are introducing support problems and creating support expense (from stale config files, unexpectedly shared config files, surprising events at software upgrades, and others), with no better reason than to use parts of a Linux standard that [many Linux-based operating systems intentionally do not use](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/567405/5132) and that [does not even apply to non-Linux operating systems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/98956/5132) like MacOS that your program targets.

Be warned.

Also be warned that `/etc` is not always the place that operating systems want used for this sort of thing.
It is common on the BSDs, for example, for applications to be configured to use `/usr/local/etc` rather than `/etc`.

Similarly, FreeDesktop.org standards prefer that applications use the directories specified by the `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` and `XDG_CONFIG_DIRS` environment variables.

Ironically, you are actually *moving away* from your application's "portable application" model, not making things more portable.

And [you aren't even doing the work](https://gitlab.com/Shinobi-Systems/Shinobi/-/merge_requests/221/diffs) to keep the doco in synch.

## Further reading

- Waldo Bastian, Ryan Lortie, and Lennart Poettering (2010).  *[XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html)*.  Freedesktop.org.
- Walter Glenn (2019-05-22). *[What Is a “Portable” App, and Why Does It Matter?](https://www.howtogeek.com/290358/what-is-a-portable-app-and-why-does-it-matter/)*.  HowToGeek.
- John T. Haller et al.. "[Portable App Guidelines](https://portableapps.com/about/what_is_a_portable_app#guidelines)".  *What is a portable app?*.  PortableApps.com.

Comment: On the Linux end, the XDG spec really is the answer to this question. If that progam  follows the guidelines this alleviates the need for non-FHS distros (NixOS for example) to patch it into behaving.